# LS_COLORS - .bashrc extension will not change colors

Tags: bash, ls, ls-colors

Here there, 
           I have been trying to get .bashrc to be the same colors I set my .profile and .bash_profile. The lscolors.sh file contains what is below and I load that up in my .profile file. Please help me shed some light on this. Been going nuts.

---

`LS_COLORS='bd=38;5;68:ca=38;5;17:cd=38;5;113;1:di=38;5;30:do=38;5;127:ex=38;5;208;1:pi=38;5;126:fi=0:ln=target:mh=38;5;222;1:no=0:or=48;5;196;38;5;232;1:ow=38;5;220;1:sg=48;5;3;38;5;0:su=38;5;220;1;3;100;1:so=38;5;197:st=38;5;86;48;5;234:tw=48;5;235;38;5;139;3:*README=38;5;220;1:*README.rst=38;5;220;1:*README.md=38;5;220;1:*LICENSE=38;5;220;1:*COPYING=38;5;220;1:*INSTALL=38;5;220;1:*COPYRIGHT=38;5;220;1:*AUTHORS=38;5;220;1:*HISTORY=38;5;220;1:*CONTRIBUTORS=38;5;220;1:*PATENTS=38;5;220;1:*VERSION=38;5;220;1:*NOTICE=38;5;220;1:*CHANGES=38;5;220;1:*.log=38;5;190:*.profile=38;5;75:*.bash_profile=38;5;75:*.bashrc=38;5;75:*.txt=38;5;214:*.etx=38;5;184:*.info=38;5;184:*.markdown=38;5;184:*.md=38;5;184:*.mkd=38;5;184:*.nfo=38;5;184:*.pod=38;5;184:*.rst=38;5;184:*.tex=38;5;184:*.textile=38;5;184:*.bib=38;5;178:*.json=38;5;178:*.jsonl=38;5;178:*.ndjson=38;5;178:*.msg=38;5;178:*.pgn=38;5;178:*.rss=38;5;178:*.xml=38;5;178:*.fxml=38;5;178:*.toml=38;5;178:*.yaml=38;5;178:*.yml=38;5;178:*.RData=38;5;178:*.rdata=38;5;178:*.xsd=38;5;178:*.dtd=38;5;178:*.sgml=38;5;178:*.rng=38;5;178:*.rnc=38;5;178:*.cbr=38;5;141:*.cbz=38;5;141:*.chm=38;5;141:*.djvu=38;5;141:*.pdf=38;5;141:*.PDF=38;5;141:*.mobi=38;5;141:*.epub=38;5;141:*.docm=38;5;111;4:*.doc=38;5;111:*.docx=38;5;111:*.odb=38;5;111:*.odt=38;5;111:*.rtf=38;5;111:*.odp=38;5;166:*.pps=38;5;166:*.ppt=38;5;166:*.pptx=38;5;166:*.ppts=38;5;166:*.pptxm=38;5;166;4:*.pptsm=38;5;166;4:*.csv=38;5;78:*.tsv=38;5;78:*.ods=38;5;112:*.xla=38;5;76:*.xls=38;5;112:*.xlsx=38;5;112:*.xlsxm=38;5;112;4:*.xltm=38;5;73;4:*.xltx=38;5;73:*.pages=38;5;111:*.numbers=38;5;112:*.key=38;5;166:*config=1:*cfg=1:*conf=1:*rc=1:*authorized_keys=1:*known_hosts=1:*.ini=1:*.plist=1:*.viminfo=1:*.pcf=1:*.psf=1:*.hidden-color-scheme=1:*.hidden-tmTheme=1:*.last-run=1:*.merged-ca-bundle=1:*.sublime-build=1:*.sublime-commands=1:*.sublime-keymap=1:*.sublime-settings=1:*.sublime-snippet=1:*.sublime-project=1:*.sublime-workspace=1:*.tmTheme=1:*.user-ca-bundle=1:*.git=38;5;197:*.gitignore=38;5;240:*.gitattributes=38;5;240:*.gitmodules=38;5;240:*.awk=38;5;172:*.bash=38;5;172:*.bat=38;5;172:*.BAT=38;5;172:*.sed=38;5;172:*.sh=38;5;172:*.zsh=38;5;172:*.vim=38;5;172:*.kak=38;5;172:*.csh=38;5;172:*.ahk=38;5;41:*.py=38;5;41:*.ipynb=38;5;41:*.rb=38;5;41:*.gemspec=38;5;41:*.pl=38;5;208:*.PL=38;5;160:*.t=38;5;114:*.msql=38;5;222:*.mysql=38;5;222:*.pgsql=38;5;222:*.sql=38;5;222:*.css=38;5;125;1:*.less=38;5;125;1:*.sass=38;5;125;1:*.scss=38;5;125;1:*.htm=38;5;125;1:*.html=38;5;125;1:*.jhtm=38;5;125;1:*.mht=38;5;125;1:*.eml=38;5;125;1:*.mustache=38;5;125;1:*.coffee=38;5;074;1:*.java=38;5;074;1:*.js=38;5;074;1:*.mjs=38;5;074;1:*.jsm=38;5;074;1:*.jsp=38;5;074;1:*.php=38;5;81:*.ctp=38;5;81:*.twig=38;5;81:*Dockerfile=38;5;155:*.dockerignore=38;5;240:*Makefile=38;5;155:*MANIFEST=38;5;243:*pm_to_blib=38;5;240:*.diff=48;5;197;38;5;232:*.patch=48;5;197;38;5;232;1:*.bmp=38;5;97:*.dicom=38;5;97:*.tiff=38;5;97:*.tif=38;5;97:*.TIFF=38;5;97:*.cdr=38;5;97:*.flif=38;5;97:*.gif=38;5;97:*.icns=38;5;97:*.ico=38;5;97:*.jpeg=38;5;97:*.JPG=38;5;97:*.jpg=38;5;97:*.nth=38;5;97:*.png=38;5;97:*.psd=38;5;97:*.pxd=38;5;97:*.pxm=38;5;97:*.xpm=38;5;97:*.webp=38;5;97:*.ai=38;5;99:*.eps=38;5;99:*.epsf=38;5;99:*.drw=38;5;99:*.ps=38;5;99:*.svg=38;5;99:*.avi=38;5;114:*.divx=38;5;114:*.IFO=38;5;114:*.m2v=38;5;114:*.m4v=38;5;114:*.mkv=38;5;114:*.MOV=38;5;114:*.mov=38;5;114:*.mp4=38;5;114:*.mpeg=38;5;114:*.mpg=38;5;114:*.ogm=38;5;114:*.rmvb=38;5;114:*.sample=38;5;114:*.wmv=38;5;114:*.3g2=38;5;115:*.3gp=38;5;115:*.gp3=38;5;115:*.webm=38;5;115:*.gp4=38;5;115:*.asf=38;5;115:*.flv=38;5;115:*.ts=38;5;115:*.ogv=38;5;115:*.f4v=38;5;115:*.VOB=38;5;115;1:*.vob=38;5;115;1:*.ass=38;5;117:*.srt=38;5;117:*.ssa=38;5;117:*.sub=38;5;117:*.sup=38;5;117:*.vtt=38;5;117:*.3ga=38;5;137;1:*.S3M=38;5;137;1:*.aac=38;5;137;1:*.amr=38;5;137;1:*.au=38;5;137;1:*.caf=38;5;137;1:*.dat=38;5;137;1:*.dts=38;5;137;1:*.fcm=38;5;137;1:*.m4a=38;5;137;1:*.mid=38;5;137;1:*.mod=38;5;137;1:*.mp3=38;5;137;1:*.mp4a=38;5;137;1:*.oga=38;5;137;1:*.ogg=38;5;137;1:*.opus=38;5;137;1:*.s3m=38;5;137;1:*.sid=38;5;137;1:*.wma=38;5;137;1:*.ape=38;5;136;1:*.aiff=38;5;136;1:*.cda=38;5;136;1:*.flac=38;5;136;1:*.alac=38;5;136;1:*.midi=38;5;136;1:*.pcm=38;5;136;1:*.wav=38;5;136;1:*.wv=38;5;136;1:*.wvc=38;5;136;1:*.afm=38;5;66:*.fon=38;5;66:*.fnt=38;5;66:*.pfb=38;5;66:*.pfm=38;5;66:*.ttf=38;5;66:*.otf=38;5;66:*.woff=38;5;66:*.woff2=38;5;66:*.PFA=38;5;66:*.pfa=38;5;66:*.7z=38;5;40:*.a=38;5;40:*.arj=38;5;40:*.bz2=38;5;40:*.cpio=38;5;40:*.gz=38;5;40:*.lrz=38;5;40:*.lz=38;5;40:*.lzma=38;5;40:*.lzo=38;5;40:*.rar=38;5;40:*.s7z=38;5;40:*.sz=38;5;40:*.tar=38;5;40:*.tgz=38;5;40:*.xz=38;5;40:*.z=38;5;40:*.zip=38;5;40:*.zipx=38;5;40:*.zoo=38;5;40:*.zpaq=38;5;40:*.zst=38;5;40:*.zstd=38;5;40:*.zz=38;5;40:*.apk=38;5;215:*.ipa=38;5;215:*.deb=38;5;215:*.rpm=38;5;215:*.jad=38;5;215:*.jar=38;5;215:*.cab=38;5;215:*.pak=38;5;215:*.pk3=38;5;215:*.vdf=38;5;215:*.vpk=38;5;215:*.bsp=38;5;215:*.dmg=38;5;215:*.r[0-9]{0,2}=38;5;239:*.zx[0-9]{0,2}=38;5;239:*.z[0-9]{0,2}=38;5;239:*.part=38;5;239:*.iso=38;5;124:*.bin=38;5;124:*.nrg=38;5;124:*.qcow=38;5;124:*.sparseimage=38;5;124:*.toast=38;5;124:*.vcd=38;5;124:*.vmdk=38;5;124:*.accdb=38;5;60:*.accde=38;5;60:*.accdr=38;5;60:*.accdt=38;5;60:*.db=38;5;60:*.fmp12=38;5;60:*.fp7=38;5;60:*.localstorage=38;5;60:*.mdb=38;5;60:*.mde=38;5;60:*.sqlite=38;5;60:*.typelib=38;5;60:*.pacnew=38;5;33:*.un~=38;5;241:*.orig=38;5;241:*.BUP=38;5;241:*.bak=38;5;241:*.o=38;5;241:*core=38;5;241:*.mdump=38;5;241:*.rlib=38;5;241:*.dll=38;5;241:*.swp=38;5;244:*.swo=38;5;244:*.tmp=38;5;244:*.sassc=38;5;244:*.pid=38;5;248:*.state=38;5;248:*lockfile=38;5;248:*lock=38;5;248:*.err=38;5;160;1:*.error=38;5;160;1:*.stderr=38;5;160;1:*.aria2=38;5;241:*.dump=38;5;241:*.stackdump=38;5;241:*.zcompdump=38;5;241:*.zwc=38;5;241:*.pcap=38;5;29:*.cap=38;5;29:*.dmp=38;5;29:*.DS_Store=38;5;239:*.localized=38;5;239:*.CFUserTextEncoding=38;5;239:*.allow=38;5;112:*.deny=38;5;196:*.service=38;5;45:*@.service=38;5;45:*.socket=38;5;45:*.swap=38;5;45:*.device=38;5;45:*.mount=38;5;45:*.automount=38;5;45:*.target=38;5;45:*.path=38;5;45:*.timer=38;5;45:*.snapshot=38;5;45:*.application=38;5;116:*.cue=38;5;116:*.description=38;5;116:*.directory=38;5;116:*.m3u=38;5;116:*.m3u8=38;5;116:*.md5=38;5;116:*.properties=38;5;116:*.sfv=38;5;116:*.theme=38;5;116:*.torrent=38;5;116:*.urlview=38;5;116:*.webloc=38;5;116:*.lnk=38;5;39:*CodeResources=38;5;239:*PkgInfo=38;5;239:*.nib=38;5;57:*.car=38;5;57:*.dylib=38;5;241:*.entitlements=1:*.pbxproj=1:*.strings=1:*.storyboard=38;5;196:*.xcconfig=1:*.xcsettings=1:*.xcuserstate=1:*.xcworkspacedata=1:*.xib=38;5;208:*.asc=38;5;192;3:*.bfe=38;5;192;3:*.enc=38;5;192;3:*.gpg=38;5;192;3:*.signature=38;5;192;3:*.sig=38;5;192;3:*.p12=38;5;192;3:*.pem=38;5;192;3:*.pgp=38;5;192;3:*.p7s=38;5;192;3:*id_dsa=38;5;192;3:*id_rsa=38;5;192;3:*id_ecdsa=38;5;192;3:*id_ed25519=38;5;192;3:*.iml=38;5;166:';
export LS_COLORS`

Comment: Does your version of `ls` *use* `LS_COLORS`? The BSD version of `ls` uses `LSCOLORS` instead.

Comment: I'm using this: `alias ls="ls -halX --color=auto"`. LS version 8.28

Comment: It uses LS_COLORS variable

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. 
So what the LS_COLORS interpreter is doing for the `ls --color="auto"` command is reading the code left to right. 
So if I declare `*.bashrc=38;5;184:` before `*.bash=38;5;179:` then the interpreter is going to default to the rule for file extension `.bash` because it is the last rule that it matches. 
Hope this helps someone. 
PS. I just figured out how to format in StackOverflow, sorry for my original question being poorly formatted.